# Accessing file by relative path through console in R studio works but not in a markdown document

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to load a csv file in R studio using relative path.

**The absolute path to the file I am trying to open is:**

```
"C:\Users\E0434232\Documents\PlatformIO\R DS\R Projects\DOE Practice from Tutorials\data\politeness_data.csv"
```

**My Working directory in R studio**

```
C:/Users/E0434232/Documents/PlatformIO/R DS/R Projects/DOE Practice from Tutorials"
```

**Location of my markdown file**

```
"C:\Users\E0434232\Documents\PlatformIO\R DS\R Projects\DOE Practice from Tutorials\r_data\Random Effects Model\Mixed Model Tutorial - Bodo Winter.rmd"
```

**Relative path that I am trying to open the file**

```
read.csv("./data/politeness_data.csv")
```

The relative path works in the console and it sucessfully opens the file. However when I use the same in R markdown to load the file it gives the following error:

```
cannot open file './data/politeness_data.csv': No such file or directoryError in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
```

I am really confused why it's not opening the file as the path works fine in the console. How can it be fixed?

Comment: Maybe when Rmarkdown is run the working directory changes? Try printing the working directory just before reading the file, so that you can see if the directory is the one you was expecting.

Comment: I have already tried that so I am sure that the wd is correct. Running getwd() from both the console and from within the markdown document gives me the same wd. when I try to knit the document it doesn't and gives the file opening error.

Comment: Added the markdown file path in the original post. I have already opened it using the absolute path but it should also work with the relative path

Comment: try `../.../../data/politeness_data.csv`

Comment: You just need your `data` Folder as a sub folder under your `r_data` folder and calling it with relative file path would work

Answer (score 2):

when Rmarkdown is knitted using the knit button in R studio the working directory is set to the folder containing the `.Rmd` file, thus u need to change the path to `../../../data/politeness_data.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Here are two suggestions :

1 - Keep the csv file in the same folder as markdown file and you can read the file directly.

```
data <- read.csv("politeness_data.csv")
```

2 - Use complete path of the file.

```
data <- read.csv("C:\Users\E0434232\Documents\PlatformIO\R DS\R Projects\DOE Practice from Tutorials\data\politeness_data.csv")
```

You can also look into [here](https://github.com/r-lib/here) package which makes it easy to reference files if above options are not suitable for you.